# Getting IP Packets from NIC in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, packet-capture

I am working on some kind of Router Project.
I need ethernet frames/ IP Packets to work correctly.
However, normal packet sniffing can't work, because it makes **two copies** of packets.

Is there a way to **prevent Kernel stack** from getting packets and instead getting to my app (Kernel module) ?
Does it requires explicit driver modification or any other alternative ?
I'm trying to use Intel E1000e drivers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing linux kernel as a router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449283/implementing-linux-kernel-as-a-router)

Comment: Well, the mentioned duplicate asks about changing "Kernel Algorithms", while my question is about direct NIC access or "Kernel bypass".

Comment: netfilter provides the ability you need (steal packets, prevent them going to the kernel stack, no driver modifications needed). Go learn about it. Then, if you still have specific questions, ask them.